# Unable to find server dropdown in pgadmin4

Tags: pgadmin-4

I am unable to find plus symbol or dropdown at server in pgadmin4.

Attached the image of error message. Please help.

[image]

Comment: Have you previously created any servers?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Omari.No severs created so far...pgadmin4 installed installed yesterday only.

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on `Servers` and creating one?

Comment: yes..i can do it.But i dont know what to do next.I started learning SQL

Comment: What Operating System are you using?

Comment: Windows 2010, 64-bit Operating system with 4GB RAM.

Comment: And you have already installed `PostgreSQL`?

Comment: Hi Omari,i am all set now.Its good.I uninstalled everything and installed  with earlier version 10 and 32 bit(earlier it was 64bit).Thank you again for all your time and support.